# Installing SML/NJ library

Tags: unit-testing, sml, ml

I need to install [QCheck/SML](http://contrapunctus.net/league/haques/qcheck/) unit test library for ML.

I could git clone the code, and create the `.cm` file, but I'm not sure how to copy the generated file into where. The document simply says (http://contrapunctus.net/league/haques/qcheck/qcheck_2.html):

> 2.1 SML/NJ
>
> For Standard ML of New Jersey, the CM library specification ‘qcheck.cm’ should be all you need. The default target of make -f
>   Makefile.nj will ask CM to build and stabilize this library. This
>   creates a file ‘.cm/x86-unix/qcheck.cm’ (alter the arch/os tag as
>   needed) which may be copied into the standard CM library path and
>   added to the ‘pathconfig’.

I used `brew install smlnj` for the ML installation in Mac, so I have `SMLNJ_HOME` at `/usr/local/Cellar/smlnj/100.78/SMLNJ_HOME`.

[image]

What is the CM path library in this? In general, how to install a library into SML/NJ?

### Edit

From Matt's answer, this is how I made it work.

#### Setup

1. Copy the whole qcheck directory into `/usr/local/Cellar/smlnj/110.78/SMLNJ_HOME/lib`.
2. Make `~/.smlnj-pathconfig` file.
3. Add `qcheck.cm /usr/local/Cellar/smlnj/110.78/SMLNJ_HOME/lib/qcheck` in the file.

#### Usage (in REPL)

1. CM.make "$/qcheck.cm";
2. open QCheck;

#### Things to consider.

1. I couldn't use the stabilized libraries (qcheck/.cm/x86-unix/qcheck.cm). So, I had to copy the whole directory.
2. For user's library, I think the install location can be anywhere, as the `~/.smlnj-pathconfig` can point to the directory.
3. For importing a structure in the same directory, `use "FILENAME";` is needed instead of `CM.make`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CM library path is located in `SMLNJ_HOME/lib`.  You can place the `.cm` file here.  The instructions say to modify the `pathconfig` file, however, I would suggest creating a `.smlnj-pathconfig` file in your home directory instead.  You are going to want to then paste the following line into that file:

```
qcheck.cm <path to directory containing qcheck.cm file>
```

You can then reference this in one of your .cm files using the anchor name: `$/qcheck.cm`.  I've not used stabilized libraries before, and the generated .cm file is giving me a bunch of errors.  If you instead use the `qcheck.cm` file from the root directory of the qcheck repo, it seems to work for me.  Perhaps someone else can comment on why I am getting these errors.

Comment: Could you elaborate the later part? I copied the whole qcheck directory into SMLNJ_HOME/lib, and modified pathconfig by adding one line (qcheck.cm qcheck.cm), (I'll use .smlnj-pathconfig when everything is working). I tried "open QCheck;" in REPL (sml) to have an error:Error: unbound structure: QCheck.

Comment: Assuming the directory you copied into `SMLNJ/HOME/lib` is called `qcheck`, the line you should have put in your pathconfig is `qcheck.cm qcheck`.  In order to be able to use it, you then need to type `CM.make "$/qcheck.cm"` into the repl

Comment: Thanks, I updated how I made it work based on your answer.